# Finding Multiples of a Defined List in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that takes a list as input and prints only the multiples of three...can't figure it out, hoping to find some help. The list I've defined is [3, 1, 6, 2, 3, 9, 7, 9, 5, 4, 5, 12, 13, 15].

Comment: What output are you expecting, and what have you tried that didn't work so far (and why)?

Answer (score 1):

```
def multiples_of_three(input_list):
    return [y for y in input_list if y % 3 == 0]

x = [3, 1, 6, 2, 3, 9, 7, 9, 5, 4, 5, 12, 13, 15]
print(multiples_of_three(x))
```

`%` is the modulo operator in python, y is a multiple of 3 if and only if `y % 3 == 0`

Comment: very nice, pythonic and compact solution!